# How to set the width of the bar in mpchart exactly(Zooming disabled)

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Based on the dataset count the width of the bar is varying in mpchart.
Is there any possibilities to set the width of the bar as 50dp.
As per the requirement zoom has to be disable.

Even I can able to achieve partially by using `chart.zoom(2.5f, 0f, 0f, 0f);` but zoom size needs to vary based on the dataset count.

Is there any other chart engine to set exact width of the bar.

Answer (score 0):

you can control the bar width with the following method:

```
BarData barData = new BarData(...);
barData.setBarWidth(1f);
```

The number you provide for this method represents a certain interval on the x-axis. If your total axis has a range of e.g. `10k`, and you set the bar width to `1000`, the bar will cover 10% of the total x-axis range.

warning: look for `mpandroidchart` library version that includes `BarData` class.
(for example: `import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;`)